# How to extract a specific digit in each row of a pandas series containing text

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.Series looks like as follows

> ```
> O     some texts...final exam marks:50 next level:10
> 1     some texts....final exam marks he has got:54 next level:15
> 2     some texts...final marks ...some texts: 45 next best level:20
> ```

I want extract those numbers 50,54,45 from that Series. Please note that there are multiple numbers in the texts of each row.
I have tried regex, but instead of giving only those specific numbers, it is picking up all the numbers in each row. Essentially I want the numbers right after the word 
'marks'. Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. I have updated the problem now. I tried the solutions given here. In facts I tried with

> ```
> pd.Series.str.findall('?<=specific text *(\d{2})')
> ```

But getting and empty list. The representation of the example here is very much similar to the actual problem, hence I edited the post.

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
s.str.extract('.*marks:\s?(\d+)', expand = False)


0    50
1    54
2    45
```

With the update:

```
s.str.extract('.*marks.*?(\d+)', expand = False)
```

This regex considers the fact that there may or may not be a character after marks

You get

```
0    50
1    54
2    45
```

Comment: Thanks A-Za-z, but I am getting the blank series again. May be I am not making the correct approach.

Comment: In my actual problem, I am first checking whether 'marks' is there in that series. If yes, then apply 'extract' else provide NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You need look behind syntax *(?<=)*, which asserts a desired pattern is preceded by another pattern, `(?<=marks:) *([0-9]+)` extract digits after the word *marks:* followed by optional spaces:

```
s
#0         some texts...final exam marks:50 next lev...
#1         some texts....final exam marks:54 next le...
#2         some texts...final marks: 45 next best le...
#Name: 1, dtype: object

s.str.extract("(?<=marks:) *([0-9]+)", expand=False)

#0    50
#1    54
#2    45
#Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom, kindly see the revised issue.