# Python - extracting digit from a pandas series containing text

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This question has a reference ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252250)). 
I am quite new to Python and thus getting stuck in somewhat trivial issues!!! I have a data series as follows

```
         Text
0        some texts...qualifications: BE year of passing 2012
1        MCOM from XYZ University in 2007. In 2009 he obtained his MBA 
2        Academics: University / Board: XYZ University   year of passing:2014
```

Objective is to extract the years as mentioned (only the first ones) i.e. `2012,2007,2014`. Now my approach is as follows:

```
corpus = pd.Series('the above series')
corpus = corpus.str.replace(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]+')
corpus = corpus.str.lower()
if corpus.str.contains('qualifications').any():
    corpus.str.extract('.*qualifications.*?(\d{4})', expand = False)
if corpus.str.contains('university').any():
    corpus.str.extract('.*university. *?(d\{4})', expand=False)
if corpus.str.contains('academics').any():
    corpus.str.extract('.*academics. *?(d\{4})',expand=False)
```

The above approach is creating a blank series. Kindly help me in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify that expression to simply this:

#### Code:

```
corpus = corpus.str.lower().str.extract(
    '(university|academics|qualifications).*?(\d{4})', expand=False)
```

#### Test Code:

```
corpus = pd.Series("""
    some texts...qualifications: BE year of passing 2012
    MCOM from XYZ University in 2007. In 2009 he obtained his MBA 
    Academics: University / Board: XYZ University   year of passing:2014
    """.split('\n')[1:-1], name='Text')

corpus = corpus.str.lower().str.extract(
    '(university|academics|qualifications).*?(\d{4})', expand=False)

print(corpus)
```

#### Results:

```
                0     1
0  qualifications  2012
1      university  2007
2       academics  2014
```

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks a lot. What is this `.split('\n')[1:-1], name='Text')`.

Comment: That is just a convenient way to build a copy and paste-able data frame(Series in this case).  The `split('\n')` breaks on new lines, and then the `[1:-1]` throws away  the first and last line which are empty.  `name=` gives the series a name.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch: Did what you have said. Many thanks.